Recoding Multiple Likert-scale Columns at Once
I usually do this the hard way, but I'm sure one of you coding experts has something less tedious.
Using this data set below:
#Example Dataset
  Q1 <- c("Agree", "Disagree", "Strongly Agree", "Strongly Disagree", "Strongly Disagree")
  Q2 <- c("Disagree", "Disagree", "Agree", "Disagree", "Strongly Disagree")
  Q3 <- c("Agree", "Disagree", "Strongly Agree", "Strongly Agree", "Strongly Agree")
  Q4 <- c("Disagree", "Disagree", "Disagree", "Strongly Disagree", "Strongly Disagree")

  data <- data.frame(Q1, Q2, Q3, Q4)

I would usually just recode it using the car package like this:
library(car)

data$Q1 <- car::recode(data$Q1, "
                       'Strongly Disagree' = 1; 
                       'Disagree' = 2; 
                       'Agree' = 3; 
                       'Strongly Agree' = 4")
data$Q2 <- car::recode(data$Q2, "
                       'Strongly Disagree' = 1; 
                       'Disagree' = 2; 
                       'Agree' = 3; 
                       'Strongly Agree' = 4")
data$Q3 <- car::recode(data$Q3, "
                       'Strongly Disagree' = 1; 
                       'Disagree' = 2; 
                       'Agree' = 3; 
                       'Strongly Agree' = 4")
data$Q4 <- car::recode(data$Q4, "
                       'Strongly Disagree' = 1; 
                       'Disagree' = 2; 
                       'Agree' = 3; 
                       'Strongly Agree' = 4")

Is there a way I can do this by column? Or, applying to the whole scale with less code?
I thought I could just specify a range of columns maybe like this, but it does not do what I want.
data <- recode(data$[1:4], "
                  'Strongly Disagree' = 1; 
                  'Disagree' = 2; 
                  'Agree' = 3; 
                  'Strongly Agree' = 4")


Alright, this is the solution. It's that dplyr is superior.
datarecoded <- data %>%                                  #select dataframe
  mutate_at(c("Q1", "Q2", "Q3", "Q4"),                   #select columns
            funs(dplyr::recode(.,"Strongly Disagree" =1, #enter recodes
                               "Disagree" =2, 
                               "Agree" =3, 
                               "Strongly Agree" =4)))

Result
Q1 Q2 Q3 Q4
1  3  2  3  2
2  2  2  2  2
3  4  3  4  2
4  1  2  4  1
5  1  1  4  1

You can also select a range within the dataframe.
datarecoded <- data %>% 
  mutate_at(c(1:3), 
            funs(dplyr::recode(.,"Strongly Disagree" =1, 
                               "Disagree" =2, 
                               "Agree" =3, 
                               "Strongly Agree" =4)))

Result 2
  Q1 Q2 Q3                Q4
1  3  2  3          Disagree
2  2  2  2          Disagree
3  4  3  4          Disagree
4  1  2  4 Strongly Disagree
5  1  1  4 Strongly Disagree


You could mutate across everything:
data |> mutate(across(
  everything(),
  ~ recode(
    .,
    "Strongly Disagree" = 1,
    "Disagree" = 2,
    "Agree" = 3,
    "Strongly Agree" = 4
  )
))


Ok, I did not figure this out completely, but I found something close to a solution. It turns out the recode function is not so great at selecting a range of columns. However, it is possible to recode an entire dataframe simultaneously. So, if you subset your data or have a whole data frame that has the same responses with the same values as in the example above, you can do a workaround.
Here is what I got working using the lapply function.
data1 <- data.frame(  #Makes the output return as dataframe
  lapply(data, FUN = function(foo) #specify dataframe
    recode(foo, "'Strongly Disagree' = 1;
           'Disagree' = 2;
           'Agree' = 3;
           'Strongly Agree' = 4")))

It would be better if I could select a specific range of columns for larger data sets with many different scales, but maybe dpylr has better solutions for that.
data1

Result for new dataframe.
  Q1 Q2 Q3 Q4
1  3  2  3  2
2  2  2  2  2
3  4  3  4  2
4  1  2  4  1
5  1  1  4  1

